# pager problem with drupal and taxonomy

Tags: drupal, module, taxonomy, pager

Ok, so this is probably a silly question, but i thought i'd put it out there anyway:
I know it's a strange solution to a simple problem, but i needed to control the listing of the nodes in the taxonomy pages, which i didn't feel i got the traditional way. So i went ahead and created a module that fetches the nodes based on taxonomy (taxonomy_select_nodes()), and i wanted a pager to go along with that.

Here's the code:

`function theModule_recipeList(){
    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    $args = explode("/",$path);
    $themePath = drupal_get_path("theme", "theTheme");`

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($args[1]);
$tid = $term[0]->tid;
$nodes = taxonomy_select_nodes(array($tid));

$output = "<div id='recipeListWrapper'>";
while($row = db_fetch_object($nodes)){
    $node = node_load($row->nid);

    if($node->uid != 1){
        $userClass="user";
    }
    else{
        $userClass="admin";
    }
    $output .= "
        <div class='receptThumbnailWrapper'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <img src='".base_path().$themePath."/graphics/recept-default-small.png' />
                <h3><a href='".base_path() . $node->path."'>".$node->title."</a></h3>
                <div class='recipeType $userClass'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ";
}
$output .= "</div>";

return $output;
```

}

Now, the module works as i planned and all (even though it is a duct tape sort of solution, i know), and the pager prints and works. The problem is that the pager prints before anything else.

I suspect that it is because i call taxonomy_select_nodes before $output is returned, but i need it to get the nodes i want.

Please, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

/Anders

Comment: May be using Views module will be better for that. Anyway  taxonomy_select_nodes doesn't print pager, it's just catch pager parameter in function. Where did you call theModule_recipeList function?

Comment: I've made a block that outputs this content, and thats where i call the funktion ($block['recipeList']['content'] = theModule_recipeList()). The reason i thought that taxonomy_select_nodes printed the pager, was because it disappeared when i commented it out.

Answer (score 1):

As Nikit suggested, I would recommend using the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create your list. You can use an argument to select the appropriate taxonomy term from the path. That way you've got the functionality you want without the need to write and maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with the duct tape approach, you could use CSS to move the Pager below your content.

```
#div-that-holds-pager-and-content {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#div-that-holds-pager {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course that option crossed my mind (going with the duct tape thing :), but i would really like to solve it in a more "proper" way, as i thought that i would also learn something from it. However, if nothing better comes up, that sort of sollution would probably be an option.